# How do I create an artifact so it will be available for download in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a GitLab ci pipeline and I am not sure how to get it to generate an artifact with the binary file that happened in the build stage.

Here is my yml file...

```
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - art

image: golang:1.9.2

variables:
  BIN_NAME: example
  ARTIFACTS_DIR: artifacts
  GO_PROJECT: example


before_script:
  - mkdir -p ${GOPATH}/src/${GO_PROJECT}
  - mkdir -p ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/${ARTIFACTS_DIR}
  - go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
  - cp -r ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/* ${GOPATH}/src/${GO_PROJECT}/
  - cd ${GOPATH}/src/${GO_PROJECT}

test:
  stage: test


  script:
    # Run all tests
    go test -run ''


build:
  stage: build

  script:
    # Compile and name the binary as `hello`
    - go build -o hello
    # Execute the binary
    - ./hello

art:
  script:
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - ./hello
```

The test and build phases run fine but the art stage does not when it is added to the yml file.

I have found lots of examples on line but finding it hard to convert them to my exact situation.

All I want to for the artifact to appear as a download on the pipeline like in this link.

[Downloading artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#downloading-artifacts)

after trying solution suggested i get the following...

```
$ go build -o hello
$ ./hello
Heldfgdfglo 2
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: ./hello: no matching files                
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Job succeeded
```

Tried adding..

```
GOPATH: /go
```

and...

```
- cd ${GOPATH}/src/${GO_PROJECT}
```

now getting following error...

```
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: /go/src/example/hello: no matching files  
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Job succeeded
```

output shared as requested...

```
 mkdir -p ${GOPATH}/src/${GO_PROJECT}
$ mkdir -p ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/${ARTIFACTS_DIR}
$ go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
$ cp -r ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/* ${GOPATH}/src/${GO_PROJECT}/
$ cd ${GOPATH}/src/${GO_PROJECT}
$ go build -o hello
$ pwd
/go/src/example
$ ls -l hello
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1859961 Jun 19 08:27 hello
$ ./hello
Heldfgdfglo 2
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: /go/src/example/hello: no matching files  
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Job succeeded
```

Comment: The link about dowloading artifacts is dead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`./hello` is not matching your artifact path because you changed the directory before running your script.

You need to move the generated executable to the original working directory of the gitlab runner, because artifact paths can only be relative to the build directory:

```
build:
  stage: build

  script:
    # Compile and name the binary as `hello`
    - go build -o hello
    # Execute the binary
    - ./hello
    # Move to gitlab build directory
    - mv ./hello ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}

  artifacts:
    paths:
    - ./hello
```

See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/15530

Comment: For the image golang:1.9.2, you have `GOPATH=/go`.

Comment: still getting an error i have added the error details to question.

Comment: Could you share the output of `pwd`  and `ls -l hello` just after `go build -o hello` ?

Comment: I have added the new output

Comment: See new answer.

Comment: Did you also updated the artifacts path to `./hello` ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify your artifact paths in the job that creates them, since every job triggers a new, empty environment (more or less considering the cache):

```
build:
  stage: build

  script:
    # Compile and name the binary as `hello`
    - go build -o hello
    # Execute the binary
    - ./hello

  artifacts:
    paths:
    - ./hello
```

Comment: Thanks, but i tried this and although the yaml is now valid it still does not create the artifact for download, any ideas?

Comment: Try removing the `./`. If that doesn‘t work, add a call to `ls` or `find` to your script.